# Invalid hex to decimal value

Tags: c#

Attempting to convert hex to decimal but the below snippet is returning an incorrect value. Hex value is: BA51A114 and the expected results are: 3125911828.

```
string hex = "BA51A114";
MessageBox.Show(int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString());
```

This is returning: -1169055468. When converted back to hex the value is now: FFFFFFFFBA51A114.

Comment: try parsing it as a `long`.  You're overflowing the bounds of an `int` by about a billion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're overflowing the [bounds of an `int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by about a billion.  You need to parse it as a `long`:

```
string hex = "BA51A114";
MessageBox.Show(long.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString());
```

Or as [khlr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594832/khlr) points out, in this case a [`uint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx) would also be sufficient.  For another billion or so anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You are over the int max value [`2147483647`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)